# Am I right when using "make some noise"?

Tags: grammar

As title, I hear in Youtube that someone used "make some noise" and don't know if it is right or not.

Anyone knows?

Comment: This may help you : [Imperative Sentences (command)](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/type-imperative.htm)

Comment: Your question can't be answered. Please provide more context.  What do you think the person means? Why do you think there is a problem? Have you seen this, or a similar phrase, used in any other contexts?

Comment: Announcers, deejays, singers, etc, at music gigs, call out "Make some noise!" when they want the audience to shout, clap and cheer, e.g. "Hello Miami! Welcome to DJ Tiesto! Everybody make some noise!". Is this what you mean?

Comment: Presenters used to say *Please give a warm welcome to X* (X = person / group being introduced). Then they moved on to *Put your hands together for X / Let's hear it for X*, but now it's just *Make some noise for X*

Comment: Around 0:10 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=am1192zt8_M)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That's exact what I mean. I just wonder about its grammar.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with its grammar.